# Differential Geometry: Angle between coordinate lines

Tags: differential-geometry

Given the surface:
  $$x= u(3v^2 - u^2 - 1/3), y= v(3u^2 - v^2 - 1/3), z= 2uv\ .$$

Find the angle between the coordinate lines. I'm not entirely sure what is meant by coordinate lines or how to find them.

So far, I have found the partial derivates of the surface: 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} = <3v^2 - 3u^2 - 1/3, 6uv, 2v>\ , \frac{\partial}{\partial v} = <6uv, 3u^2 - 3v^2 - 1/3, 2u>\ . $$

I also calculated the first quadratic, but I'm not sure that it is necessary so I'll leave it out for now.  Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: you've found two vectors, and now you are asked to find the angle between these two vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "coordinate lines" are the curves along which $u = \text{constant}$ or 
$v = \text{constant}$. So, the angle between these curves is just the angle between partial derivative vectors. You have calculated partial derivative vectors. Now calculate the angle between them (using dot products, or some other method).